# Overwriting existing OS via expanding a partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, xubuntu, windows-7

Currently I have a dual boot of windows 7 and Xubuntu. I'd like to dedicate my whole hard drive to Xubuntu and get rid of windows 7. Is there any way I can do this without having to format my hard drive and install Xubuntu from scratch?

Also if there is a way, how can I remove the windows 7 entry from grub?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from xUbuntu install gParted with your favorite installation program. Start it up (from the menu or commandline with sudo). Select and mark all Windows partitions for "delete" and start the task.

After that is done format the unallocated space as ext4 and you will have a mountable partition. You can also enlarge your xUbuntu adding the space to your current root or any other partition that is -next- to the unallocated space.

Example: I have marked 2 partitions (fat and ntfs) that are windows. Rightclick, unmount if needed and you can then choose delete but also choose "format to" from the dropdown.

[image]

---

> Also if there is a way, how can I remove the windows 7 entry from grub?

Easiest would be to install "grub customizer" and remove it from there.